# Passing objects of redux actions to Stateless component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using React and Redux. I want to pass to my stateless component an object of (redux) actions like so:

From my container:

```
render() {
    const objectOfActions = {
      changeTitle: this.props.changeTitle,
      changeDescription: this.props.changeDescription,
    };

    return (
        <StatelessComponent
          objectOfActions={objectOfActions}
        />
    );
  }
```

So the stateless component can use the actions as follows:

```
const SuggestSessionChange = ({objectOfActions}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={objectOfActions.changeTitle}>ChangeTitle</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The actions do not however fire when passing them wrapped up in an object (though they do fire if the actions are individually passed to the stateless component). Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

Actions do in fact fire, I had a typo calling an undefined function in my stateless function.

Answer (score 0):

change the function argument as parameter. as you are not doing any destructuring of parameter

> ```
> const SuggestSessionChange = (objectOfActions) => {
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <Button onClick={objectOfActions.changeTitle}>ChangeTitle</Button>
>     </div>
>   );
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Khalid. It turns out destructuring doesn't make a difference, it was that I had a typo in my component onClick handler, see below.